# Using jQuery contains with array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops, each

Instead of writing this a bunch of times (which works):

```
$('.this--class:contains("Some text")').parent().clone().appendTo($(".other--class"));

$('.this--class:contains("Other text")').parent().clone().appendTo($(".other--class"));

$('.this--class:contains("More text")').parent().clone().appendTo($(".other--class"));
```

If trying to figure out if I can put the text items into an array and then loop through them using jQuery and then have it clone to the `.other--class`.

My example:

```
var items = [
        "Some text",
        "Other text",
        "More text"
      ];
      $.each(items, function (index, value) {
        $(".this--class:contains(value)").parent().clone().appendTo($(".other--class"));
      }
```

If I do a `console.log(value);` I can see it kick out the correct items in the console. I'm just not sure of the correct way to have `:contains()` recognize that text, or if I need to go about this differently.
Overall just looking of an easier way to not have to write the same thing over and over.

Comment: Currently "value" is part of your string. Have you tried `".this--class:contains(" + value + ")"` ?

Comment: Ahh, I did, but I was missing the correct spacing, lol! Now it seems like it's working, haha!

Comment: Voting to close as a typo since OP got a solution from the comments